# Finding one function from NDSolve of two nonlinear PDE simultaneously!

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, programming

I want to NDSolve two below partial equations :

```
s1 = NDSolve[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(f[x, y, z]\)\) == \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, 
    y\)]\((p1[y, z]*f[x, y, z])\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z, 
    z\)]\((p2[y, z]*f[x, y, z])\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, 
    z\)]\((p3[y, z]*f[x, y, z])\)\) + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, 
    z\)]\((p3[y, z]*f[x, y, z])\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\((p4[y, z]*f[x, y, z])\)\), 
 conditions1}, f, {x, 0, xmax}, {y, -ymin, 0}, {z, 0, zmax}];

 s2 = NDSolve[{\!\(
 \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(f[x, y]\)\) == \!\(
 \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\((p5[y]*
 \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\((f[x, y])\))\)\), 
 conditions2}, f, {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}];
```

In fact, I want to find one function for two regions (in first region i have f(x, y, z) and in the second region f (x, y).Can anyone guide how I solve these two equations simultaneously ? or not?

(for example is it possible by using Piecewise functions or WhenEvent command or not? How?)

thanks a lot

Comment: Why not just solve them separately? ... or did you leave out some important information about boundary conditions? Are the functions supposed to match somehow at the boundaries between the regions? What are `conditions1` and `conditions2`? More info is required.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The five `p`s also need to be defined.  Is `f[x, y]` meant to be a boundary condition for `f[x, y, z]`?  If so, for what value of `z`?  Readers may be able to help, if more information is provided, although this looks to be a difficult problem.

Comment: no, actually f [x,y] and f[x,y,z] are one function but in the region of {y, 0, ymax}, f Is only a function of a 2 variable (x,y) and in the region of {y, -ymin, 0} f Is a function of a 3 variable (x,y,z)! for the boundaries conditions, i have a initial distribution functions for two regions ( f0 [y,z] for the first region and f0[y] for the second region.)   
yes, in the boundary y=0 the answer of two PDE should be equal.

Comment: i have a distribution for each p functions.  Is it true that I solve the two equations separately and finally sum the answers together? Of course, after integrating on the y , z variables for the first region and on y for second region. (f1(x)+f2(x)).